# Browser Native Injection

Tags: javascript, c++, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

Following this script: **[#content_script.js](https://gist.github.com/adammw/5813316#file-content_script-js)**, It is a way to inject code for obtaining values which are passed in the parameters.

Or more clear (*It can be any JavaScript's functions* ):

```
(function() {
    var parse = JSON.parse;
    JSON.parse = function(){
        console.log('Getting params: ', arguments);
        return parse.apply(JSON, arguments)
    };
    JSON.parse.toString = function(){ return 'function parse() { [native code] }' };

    var wss = WebSocket.prototype.send;
    WebSocket.prototype.send = function(){
        console.log('Getting params', arguments);
        return wss.apply(this, arguments)
    }
    WebSocket.prototype.send.toString = function(){ return 'function send() { [native code] }' }
})();
```

But, in an online game I'm in a situation I should not use that method, instead I want to inject it into JavaScript engine (`Native Code`).  Not exactly I want to know how to develop, if not, what should I do?. If I must use another programming language or some method for do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very easily done. All the code below is template code, which means common copy paste for all addons, with slight tweaks. Here is a small tutorial on how to write a firefox bootstrap addon. It is basically the same thing as here but personalized for your work: https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/9025999 (i didnt include details like icon and localization though)

1. Create an empty folder on your computer
2. In it make these blank new files: bootstrap.js and install.rdf and chrome.manifest and inject.js
3. Into install.rdf paste this template:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
       <!-- This Source Code Form is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public
      - License, v. 2.0. If a copy of the MPL was not distributed with this
      - file, You can obtain one at http://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/. -->
       <RDF xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:em="http://www.mozilla.org/2004/em-rdf#">
         <Description about="urn:mozilla:install-manifest">
           <em:id>Bootstrap-Skeleton@jetpack</em:id>
           <em:version>initial</em:version>
           <em:type>2</em:type>
           <em:bootstrap>true</em:bootstrap>
           <em:unpack>false</em:unpack>

           <!-- Firefox -->
           <em:targetApplication>
             <Description>
               <em:id>{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}</em:id>
               <em:minVersion>7.0</em:minVersion>
               <em:maxVersion>27.0</em:maxVersion>
             </Description>
           </em:targetApplication>

           <!-- Front End MetaData -->
           <em:name>Bootstrap Skeleton</em:name>
           <em:description>How all bootstrap addons start.</em:description>
           <em:creator>Noitidart</em:creator>
           <em:contributor>Pat for Icon</em:contributor>
           <em:optionsType>2</em:optionsType>
         </Description>
       </RDF>
   ```
4. Now in what we pasted lets replace the contents of `<em:id>` with `DragonboundCheater@wZVanG`
5. Lets update `<em:name>` to the name of addon we want, lets name it `Dragonbound Cheater`
6. Now save that and go over to bootstrap.js
7. In bootstrap.js paste this template:

   ```
   function startup(aData, aReason) {}

   function shutdown(aData, aReason) {
       if (aReason == APP_SHUTDOWN) return;
   }

   function install() {}

   function uninstall() {}
   ```
8. Now update its contents with this:

   ```
   const {classes: Cc, interfaces: Ci, utils: Cu, results: Cr} = Components;
   Cu.import('resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm');
   var browserWinAddedTo;
   function startup(aData, aReason) {
       var recentBrowserWindow = Services.wm.getMostRecentWindow('navigator:browser');
       browserWinAddedTo = recentBrowserWindow;
       if (recentBrowserWindow.document.readyState == 'complete') { //on startup `aDOMWindow.document.readyState` is `uninitialized`
           recentBrowserWindow.messageManager.loadFrameScript('chrome://dragonboundcheater@wzvang/content/inject.js');
       } else {
           recentBrowserWindow.addEventListener('load', function () {
               recentBrowserWindow.removeEventListener('load', arguments.callee, false);
               recentBrowserWindow.messageManager.loadFrameScript('chrome://dragonboundcheater@wzvang/content/inject.js');
           }, false);
       }
   }

   function shutdown(aData, aReason) {
       if (aReason == APP_SHUTDOWN) return;
       browserWinAddedTo.messageManager.removeDelayedFrameScript('chrome://dragonboundcheater@wzvang/content/inject.js');
   }

   function install() {}

   function uninstall() {}
   ```
9. In chrome.manifest add this: `content dragonboundcheater ./`
10. In inject.js now we can do whatever js want, but lets first make sure the host matches, and also see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Multiprocess_Firefox/Frame_script_environment this tells us that the window object is refered to by the global variable `content` so wherever we want to access that we use `content` and if you want to access the js environment we do so by `content.wrappedJSObject`. So lets make inject.js be this:

    ```
    (function() {
        var window = content;
        var js = window.wrappedJSObject;


        if (window.location.host.indexOf('dragonbound.net') == -1) {
           return;
        }

        var parse = js.JSON.parse;
        js.JSON.parse = function(){
            console.log('Getting params: ', arguments);
            return parse.apply(js.JSON, arguments)
        };
        js.JSON.parse.toString = function(){ return 'function parse() { [native code] }' };

        var wss = js.WebSocket.prototype.send;
        js.WebSocket.prototype.send = function(){
            console.log('Getting params', arguments);
            return wss.apply(this, arguments)
        }
        js.WebSocket.prototype.send.toString = function(){ return 'function send() { [native code] }' }
    })();
    ```
11. Then zip all the stuff in the folder up, rename it from .zip to .xpi and drag into firefox and voila :)

Comment: Note i have a bug: On newly opened tabs its not running the script, i have to look into that, will do in a bit

Comment: @wZVanG this simple addon will work no problems if you enable/install it while dragon site is open, and you only have one firefox window with tabs, if you have multiple you have to use an iterator to go through all windows and attach.

Comment: To debug your addon use the browser console after enabling the dev preferences here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Setting_up_extension_development_environment?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Setting_up_extension_development_environment#Development_preferences

Comment: The installation was successfully. But i get this Console's line: `No chrome package registered for chrome://wzvang/content/inject.js`

Comment: Oh I made a mistake, on step 9, instead of `DragonboundCheater@wZVanG` set the id to `DragonboundCheater` apparnetly you cant have the `@` sign.

Comment: Thanks, I already understood, however I have to read the documentation how everything works. And I want to the page not to detect in any way the JavaScript's handling. Do you have any tip?

Comment: @wZVanG i dont understand your question, what do you mean not detect the js handling?

Comment: I mean if the page, in this case `dragonbound.net` may have some method to detect or know my injection?. It's what I do not want to happen.

Comment: Ah ok I see @wZVanG I cant tell you without studying their code, it depends on how they detect the injection then you'll have to work around that. Once you figure out how they detect it, then if you post another question people should be able to help you.